# How short should I trim my nails?

Tags: piano, practice

I have been advised by my piano teacher to trim my nails to prevent accidents on the keyboard (like getting a nail stuck between the keys).

How short should I trim my fingernails?

I don't want to cause damage to the inner parts of my fingernails.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short enough to not click on the keys when playing with curved fingers. I've just done mine.

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't recommend cutting your nails that close to the "meat". If you do that on your toes as well, that's like asking for an ingrown fingernail to happen.

Comment: I cut my left-hand nails that short for playing stringed instruments, and never have trouble with ingrown fingernails.  Maybe I'm just lucky.  The only trouble I had from super short nails is that it felt strange for a few weeks until I got used to it.

Comment: The clicking surely isn't a problem. Nails are there, I guess, to protect the fingertips. Yours look quite vulnerable that short.

Comment: @Tim, I guess you don't play piano?  If they click, and you play with any energy, they eventually become painful and even split

Comment: Played piano for 65 yrs! Still play in two big bands, and one jazz quartet, and keep nails as in my answer. never had any problems. And I give it stick when needed. But if mine were as short as yours, guitar and bass would be problematic. Bit of a compromise, but it's always worked like that for me.

Answer (score 6):

This guidance really should come from teacher, especially as s/he mentioned it! However, I keep mine at between 1 and 1.5mm from the skin. Bearing in mind I also play guitar and bass,it's a bit of a compromise on r.h. On the other hand (!) as long as you don't have long manicured nails such as thiose found on some ladies, you'll be o.k. Ask teacher.

Comment: The compromise I've personally reached is to leave 1-1.5mm from the pink portion of the nail and leave a longer nail on the right thumb.